# Check if Running a process string VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

For example, if the process will be, MozillaFirefox.exe, how do I do if I put: `p = Process.GetProcessesByName("Mozilla")` and find the process "`MozillaFirefox`" just one example. consider the first 5 letters: `Mozii` and find out if there is a process run that starts with "`Mozii`" 
Thanks. so new versions Process that begin with 1.7 or 1.8 or 2.1 after name are easier to find.

```
Dim p() As Process

Private Sub CheckIfRunning()
    p = Process.GetProcessesByName("Mozii")
    If p.Count > 0 Then
        ' Process is running
    Else
        ' Process is not running
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the return of all processes from `Process.GetProcesses()` using something like this:

```
p = Process.GetProcesses.Where(Function(ps) ps.ProcessName.ToLower.StartsWith("mozii")).ToArray
```